# Java Layout Positioning with NetBeans vs Eclipse

Tags: java, swing, layout, positioning

I'm trying to create a simple slideshow program like Powerpoint. In order to design its GUI, I used Netbeans and, then copied the GUI code from Netbeans to Eclipse.

Netbeans generated the following code:

```
    pg = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

    pg.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    pg.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    pg.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(255, 234));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pgLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pg);
    pg.setLayout(pgLayout);
    pgLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 357, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    pgLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pgLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 257, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );


    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 82, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(pg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 357, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(pg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 257, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
```

My problem is, I want to change the `jPanel1` on the right to my own class which extends `JPanel`. To do this, I wrote:

```
JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();  
jPanel1.add(new ToolBoxGUI("ToolBox"));
```

But when I run the code, there are no `ToolBoxGUI` class buttons on the right. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: One way to do it would be to add a bean to your Netbeans GUI. I don't have the program with me at this moment, but I think that at the right of the GUI creator, there's a toolbox. One of the options is to add a bean. You click on "Create Bean" and type in "ToolBoxGUI" as the class name. Then you can drag that onto your panel.

Comment: It's better in the long run to design your UIs by hand.  The [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) will help you understand the differences, but in general I've found `BoxLayout` (and the `Box` class), `BorderLayout`, and `FlowLayout` to be the most useful.  I've never used the [MiG layout manager](http://miglayout.com/) but I know some people really love it.  And stick with NetBeans...you'll be happier in the long run :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jPanel1` uses a GroupLayout. To be visible, your ToolBoxGUI would have to be added to this GroupLayout. If what you want is to make the ToolBoxGUI the unique component of jPanel1, then remove the code which sets the layout of jPanel1:

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 62, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
    jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
```

and replace it with

```
jPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Or, if you want to replace jPanel1 with the ToolBoxGUI, remove the same code as above, and initialize jPanel1 with

```
jPanel1 = new ToolBoxGUI();
```